# Difference between Observable.create() and Observable.fromCallable()

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

Suppose we are getting a generic `Object` from `SharedPrefs` using `.create()`:

```
return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
      String json = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
      T myClass = gson.fromJson(json, generic);
      subscriber.onNext(myClass);
      subscriber.onComplete();
    });
```

and using `.fromCallable()`:

```
return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
      String json = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
      return gson.fromJson(json, generic);
    });
```

Is there any Difference if we call `onComplete()` immediately after first emmit from `Observable.create()` and using `Observable.fromCallable()`? If so, what are the `pros/cons`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Observable.create` let's you emit multiple items while `fromCallable` emits only a single item.

You should use the latter as it is more expressive about the intent of having a single element sequence and has a slighly lower overhead.

Drawback is that you can't have an async single element source with it whereas `create` let's you delay the call to `onNext` to a later point in time.

Comment: Can you specify a more descriptive answer with examples to understand it more.

Comment: Please be more proactive and check the available RxJava documents and [wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables).