# RxJava cancel request for 'Single.fromCallable' , disposable.clear caused InterruptedIOException

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava along with AWS API Gateway in my app.

The code is here:

```
    @Override
    public Single<SearchResponse> searchPostsApiCall(String keyword, String offset) {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> client.postSearch(keyword,offset));
    }

// to call api
getCompositeDisposable().add(searchPostsApiCall(keyword,offset)
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribe(response -> onResponseReceived(response, offset, finalType), this::onError)
        );
```

The issue is that when user during search changes text too frequently and api call is already in process then i want to cancel previous call before sending new hit as i don't want response of previous hit due to changed query.

I tried using disposable.cancel too but it gives error

```
'ApiClientException: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted'
```

How can i achieve my target to save my hits? Any idea will be appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some APIs respond to cancellation by throwing an exception that can't be relayed. If such crashes are consistent, such as you always get `InterruptedIOException` from such APIs, you can ignore such exceptions specifically and thus RxJava won't know about them.

This is somewhat difficult to achieve via `fromCallable` as you have to return something non-null but you may not be able to create an instance of the type involved. Therefore, I suggest using create:

```java
Single.create(emitter -> {
    try {
        emitter.onSuccess(client.postSearch(keyword,offset));
    } catch (InterruptedIOException ex) {
        // ignore
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        emitter.onError(ex);
    }
});
```

**Edit** If you can create ąn `SearchResponse`, you can stay with `fromCallable`:

```java
Single.fromCallable(() -> {
    try {
        return client.postSearch(keyword,offset);
    } catch (InterruptedIOException ex) {
         // fromCallable won't actually emit this
        return new SearchResponse();
    }
});
```

Comment: As it is emitter, will it stop observing onSuccess/onError or not?

Comment: please see this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43791946/5110536   is there any way to get lower overhead

Comment: Why should I look at my own answer?

Comment: because in that you mentioned that 'fromCallable' is better than 'create'

Comment: Context matters. That question did not have an issue with crashing.

Comment: yes, it will help in handling crash but does it has any cons too? and what about 'As it is emitter, will it stop observing onSuccess/onError or not? '

Comment: It's a tradeoff. Slightly more overhead with `create` in exchange for better control or the need for a global error handler with `fromCallable`. You decide. Also I don't understand "will it stop observing". When both run on a scheduler, they will get interrupted upon dispose.

Comment: It says that 'Exception java.io.InterruptedIOException is never thrown  in the corresponding try block'

Comment: Then catch `ApiClientException` and see if the cause is `InterruptedIOException`.

Comment: ok, and can you please elaborate '// fromCallable won't actually emit this' comment. and what overhead Single.create has over Single.fromcallable.

Comment: If you are that interested in the details, please see [SingleFromCallable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/single/SingleFromCallable.java#L35) and [SingleCreate](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/single/SingleCreate.java#L46).

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i think fromCallable is working for me in happy scenario. Can you please elaborate your comment '// fromCallable won't actually emit this'.

Comment: [This line](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/single/SingleFromCallable.java#L55) will prevent it.

Comment: that checks isDisposed, you mean for every request that throws exception the request will be disposed by library itself? and then what's purpose to return new empty instance instead of null?

Comment: The issue that i realized is that using Single.callable if i catch ApiClientException and if that is not for InterruptedIOException then my actual errors are being ignored and don't reach to onError method. :(]